# Target Audience missing in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

The "Target Audience" web part property is missing in SharePoint 2013.  It was available at some point but now it does not show up.

How can I enable it?. not sure why its not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Which web part is missing the "Target Audience" property? Can I verify you are looking for this property in the right place, in the Advanced section beneath the "Import Error Message" property?

Please have a try to below ways firstly and see if it will be fixed:

1. Enable audience targeting in SharePoint 2010 Site Collection
   Go to Site Setting >> Click on "Site collection navigation" >> Make sure "Enable Audience targeting" is checked.
2. Check the User Profile Service is running.
3. Make sure the User Profile Service is listed in the web application's service connections.
4. IISRESET

Here are some related threads for your reference:

1. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11184/target-audiences-property-not-visible-in-web-part-tool-pane
2. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/92e96d15-298f-4bd6-8151-a3a530ae3895/sharepoint-2010-missing-target-audience-option-in-webpart-tried-several-suggested-solutions?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Comment: yes, I am looking at the advance section beneath the "import error message".  I am using SharePoint 2013 and Enable Audience targeting" is checked

Comment: thank for the help but all the configuration is fine.. I restart IIS , recycle the app pool but nothing seem to enable this option..